# UPDATE SQL not working with my PHP Form

Tags: php, sql, oop, sql-update

I have a html form on a page called edit.php?cat=1. The form has the fields cat_name, cat_description and cat_id. I am trying to update the current fields with new values but the code execution dies when it reaches the point of calling the function  (which leads me to think it's an error with the SQL query).

Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong here?

```
function update_cat($name, $desc, $id){
 $db = getDB();
 $sql = "UPDATE categories SET cat_name = ".$name.", cat_description = ".$desc." WHERE cat_id = ".$id;
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
}

$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$top = $_GET['top'];

if($cat)
{
 if(isset($_POST['catSubmit']))
 {
   $name = $_POST['cat_name'];
   $desc = $_POST['cat_description'];
   $cat = $_POST['cat_id'];

   update_cat($name, $desc, $cat);
 }
}
```

Comment: What database is this? And why 'prepare' if you don't care?

Comment: Is cat_name and cat_description are strings? if so, you need to wrap them inside a single quote. `$sql = "UPDATE categories SET cat_name = '".$name."', cat_description = '".$desc."' WHERE cat_id = ".$id;`

Comment: @developer: I wouldn't suggest an way to make SQL-injection work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sure, the code is insecure, but i just want to point him to the problem in his code

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have some special characters in $name or $desc. You should use prepare with parameter markers and bind_param as pointed out here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add single quotes in your SQL query, at $name and $desc.

`$sql = "
UPDATE categories
SET cat_name = '".$name."',
cat_description = '".$desc."' WHERE cat_id = ".$id;`

To prevent SQL injection:
`$name = htmlentities($name);`
`$desc = htmlentities($desc);`